# Is there any equivalent to TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName method in .NET

Tags: c#, unicode, sharepoint-2010, taxonomy, csom

I wonder if an equivalent method exists for the `TaxonomyItem. NormalizeName` method from SharePoint in `C#`.

The method is located in the namespace `Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy`, but only available on the SharePoint server itself. In my opinion, the `CSOM` of `SharePoint 2010` does not have a corresponding method.

The function itself converts certain characters into unicode characters. The best example of this is the `&` sign. In the taxonomy, the character is stored as fullwidth ampersand.

Here is an example:

```
Lisa & Tom
```

is stored in SharePoint as follows:

```
Lisa ＆ Tom
```

If, for example, you want to place a `CAML query` on the server in the client application and such a special character is contained in the search string, the `CAML query` will not find any corresponding results.

At the moment we solve it with a simple self-written function, which is not complete, because we don't know all characters, which are converted to unicode.

Here is a better way to use this code or an equivalent function to `TaxonomyItem. NormalizeName`:

```
public static string ConvertStringToUnicode(string inputString)
{
   try
   {
      return Regex.Replace(inputString, "&", "\uff06").Replace("\"", "\uff02");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding:

> In my opinion, the CSOM of SharePoint 2010 does not have a
>   corresponding method.

i have not found any evidence of that, at least [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyitem.normalizename(v=office.14).aspx) says it is supported in SharePoint **2010** CSOM API, here is an example how to utilize it:

```
var name = "Lisa & Tom";
var result = TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName(ctx, name);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

where `ctx` is the instance of `ClientContext`

But if you prefer no dependency to SharePoint libraries, here is the .Net version:

```
public static string NormalizeName(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
       return null;
    var trimSpacesRegex = new Regex("\\s+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    return trimSpacesRegex.Replace(name, " ").Replace('&', '＆').Replace('"', '＂');
}
```

Comment: thanks for providing that offline function.  It's not even about having no dependency, but to avoid making a call to the server just to get a normalized string.  Useful for batch operations.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [String.Normalize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.normalize(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Returns a new string whose binary representation is in a particular Unicode normalization form.

Comment: No, that's not working. The `&` sign still is `&` and not `＆`

Comment: Have you tried all 4 options? It has the ability to compose *and* decompose.

Comment: No, I but I will check. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you mean the `NormalizationForm`s parameter, don't you? I've tested all, but no one has the expected result.